# Outlook VBA that changes email signature based on recipient domains?

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to change my email signature depending on which domain I am emailing.

If I am emailing internally (my company's domain) use a short signature. If at least one recipient is external use a long signature.

I am guessing I need to intercept some sort of "Send" event and then iterate through the recipients.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't make it complicated with a macro. Add different signatures, name them, and then the fastest way to insert signatures is to use the keyboard shortcuts:

- Under **Outlook 2003** or earlier (no ribbon): [Alt] i + S, then select a signature.
- Under **Outlook 2007** or later (ribbon):

  - Either do [Alt] N + AS, then select a signature.
  - Or first add the signature button to the *Quick Access Toolbar* (just do a right-click on button and *Add*). Then you can use [Alt] + 1, and select a signature.